# Order of acquisition: In which sequence do French children learn the language?

Tags: apprentissage

I'm not proficient enough in French yet to give the exact equivalents. I was just wondering if there's a corresponding French morpheme sequence that I could use to learn the language. In other words; in which sequence do French children learn the language?

The following is a messy copy-and-paste job from

https://www.asha.org/Practice-Portal/Clinical-Topics/Late-Language-Emergence/Grammatical-Morphemes-in-Order-of-Acquisition/

to give you an idea of the English-learning sequence.

> Grammatical Morpheme
>   Example
>   Present progressive  (-ing) Baby crying.
>   *in*
>   *on*
>   Plural regular (-s)
>   Past irregular
>   Possessive  ('s)
>   Uncontractible copula  (used as main verb)
>   Articles (a, the)
>   Past regular  (-ed) 
>   Third person regular  (-s)
>   Third person irregular
>   Uncontractible auxiliary
>   Contractible copula 
>   Contractible auxiliary

Comment: But what would be the -ing form in French, considering there's no progressive present in French? Please, edit your question to make the comparison between an English grammar structure, and a French one.

Comment: It's difficult to think there should be anything else but a humourous quirk in this contention of "irregular verb endings before regular", that being on the count of the few verbs that do not change (burst, cast, put, quit); nevertheless, notwithstanding any possible lack of seriousness in it, the reality it suggests seems to have no counterpart in the Learning of French. You might be interested by this source on French children's psycholinguistics (more likely than not such facts should be mentionned in it) : https://www.cultura.com/psycholinguistique-de-l-enfant-tea-9782603022672.html .

Comment: Here is another source that is available for reading online: https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1974_num_22_1_5676